# Why is the limit of this function tending to 1?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

$$  \lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{(x^2+x)\left(\ln\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^2}\right) $$

I know the answer is 1, but why does it tend to 1? 
Can you manipulate the function and the "$\ln$" to make it obvious?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $$  \lim_{x\to +\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(x^2+x)\left[\ln \left(\frac{x+1}{x} \right) \right]^2}\right)? $$

Comment: $\log\left(\frac {x +1}x\right)=\log\left(1+\frac {1}x\right)$ could help.

Answer (score 1):

$$  \lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{(x^2+x)\left(\ln\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^2}\right) $$

Use $u=\frac{1}{x}$

So we have $$\lim_{u\to 0} \left(\frac{u^2}{(1+u)\left(\ln\left[1+u\right]\right)^2}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{\lim_{u\to 0}(1+u)}\cdot \frac{1}{\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\left(\ln\left[1+u\right]\right)^2}{u^2}} $$
$$=\frac{1}{\lim_{u\to 0}(1+u)}\cdot \frac{1}{\left(\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}\right)^2}$$
$$= \frac{1}{1+0}\cdot \frac{1}{1}$$
$$=1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\log (\frac{x+1}{x})=\log (1+\frac{1}{x})$$
and with $\frac{1}{x}\to 0$
we get 
$$\log (1+\frac{1}{x})\to\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: You should be more specific about what is meant by $\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)\to\frac1x$. It doesn't really say anything. Think about $\sim$ for "[asymptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis)"

Comment: I explain it by saying that as $1/x\to 0$ which means as it goes smaller or x grows larger the function approches that

Comment: All that says is that both tend to $0$.

Comment: That's why it's a hint ;) I haven't given the entire solution to let him do the rest of the work, if he work on that he'll see that something in the, denominator I think it is?, gets divided by larger and larger number while another is just a 1.